# Angular select options not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch

I am trying to create dropdown of days of the month in angular where the selected number will be passed into an elasticsearch query. 
The problem is that in order to have an 'all days' option the query requires all to be entered as '*'. 
The code works if I also display the all option with the * like so, but obviously that's not very readable for the user:

js

```
$scope.daysInMonthArray = ['*']
$scope.day = $scope.daysInMonthArray[0];

$scope.daysInMonth = function (month, year) {
  return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate()
};

for (var i=0; i < $scope.daysInMonth(n, $scope.year); i++) {
  $scope.daysInMonthArray.push(i + 1)
}
```

html

```
<select
  class="form-control"
  ng-model="day"
  ng-options="day for day in daysInMonthArray">
</select>
```

And I have tried to get it to display the word 'all' with the value of '*', in the following way, but it does not work. What it sends back to the query just says '[object Object]'.

js

```
$scope.daysInMonthArray = [{'name': 'all', 'value': '*'}]
$scope.day = $scope.daysInMonthArray[0];

$scope.daysInMonth = function (month, year) {
  return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate()
};

for (var i=0; i < $scope.daysInMonth(n, $scope.year); i++) {
  $scope.daysInMonthArray.push({'name': i + 1, 'value': i + 1})
}
```

html

```
<select
  class="form-control"
  ng-model="day"
  ng-options="day as day.name for day in daysInMonthArray track by day.value">
</select>
```

Am I writing the second one incorrectly or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: try to use Index of the option , if you select all the pass that index and then fire your query for that index. You can do it by using value of dropdown also.

Comment: How are you using the value to query elasticsearch. You should only need to use 'day.value'

Comment: I didnt see your second implementation before posting my answer. It looks good. I am deleting my answer.

Comment: @NagaSandeep no, put it back! i just implemented your answer and it worked :) i had written the ng-options incorrectly and i needed .value at the end of $scope.day

Comment: Please add plunker/jsFidddle

Comment: @IAmAkittycatAMA added it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass the days as value and label object to the select. That way we can configure what goes into value and what goes into label.

**app.js**

```
  var n = 1;
  $scope.year = 2016;

  $scope.daysInMonthArray = [{'value':'*', 'label':'all'}]
  $scope.day = $scope.daysInMonthArray[0];

  $scope.daysInMonth = function (month, year) {
    return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate()
  }

  for (var i=0; i < $scope.daysInMonth(n, $scope.year); i++) {
    $scope.daysInMonthArray.push(
      {
        'value':i + 1,
        'label':i+1
      })
  }

  $scope.day = $scope.daysInMonthArray[0].value;
```

Accordingly your select will be

```
 <select
  class="form-control"
  ng-model="day"
  ng-options="day.value as day.label for day in daysInMonthArray">
</select>
```